# Pivot JSON Object With JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, pivot-table

I have a data set that I need to pivot in order to represent in a grid on screen.

I wanted to do this in the database, but the issue is the number of columns that can be returned by the query is dynamic and fluctuates based on the search criteria.

The dataset from the query looks like this:
[image]

And I need to represent it on the screen like this:
[image]

Essentially each sample ID needs to be its own line, with the test method ID's and results on the line with it.

My plan is to do the pivot on the front end, using a JQuery library if possible.

I wanted to use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/json-to-pivot-json but i do not belive it will work because of their limitation: **Only supports single column, row and value for pivoting for now.**

Does anyone have any libraries to recommend, or examples a pivot being done with a large dataset like I have?

All the examples I have found are very basic doing only 3 columns.

Comment: Please take a peak at the [posting rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), which state: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow."* You should instead come to us with a solution you've already implemented, explain why it isn't working, and we can help debug.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that it is the first 9 columns which are "static"? Have you considered writing your own pivot logic? Shouldn't be terribly difficult given the structure of your data.

Comment: In addition to what Forty3 says, jQuery is not the tool to use and I'm not sure why that is your tool of choice. The better choice for data manipulation is lodash or underscore.

Comment: @Forty3 Correct, the TM_ID and corresponding RESULT need to be pivoted to a single row for their sample. All others are static. I can do this in the database with a pivot clause or with case statements, but it wont work cause i would then need a dynamically built Java object on the backend because i do not know what test methods are going to get returned.

Comment: It might be easier and more performant to make two queries to the backend. Then couple up the data.

Comment: Naive initial thought - two passes through your dataset: the first to build a hash of properties (hash key being a simple hash of the 9 fixed columns, properties for the 9 fixed columns, and dynamic property names being the TM_ID values) along with a separate array of all possible TM_ID values. Then a second pass constructing a new dataset walking the hash along with each of the entries in the TM_ID array. Like I said, naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was unable to find any library that would do a pivot for me in JQuery.

So, I created my own pivot function in Java to build a distinct list of the data, and do the pivot in a single pass through.

```
    public List<JSONObject> getDistinctResultsAndPivot(List<LabInquiryDetail> results){
    List<JSONObject> pivotData = new ArrayList<>();
    String prevSampeId = "";

    for (LabInquiryDetail result : results) {
        /*
         * If sample IDs do not match, it is either the first record in the result set,
         * or a new record we have not looked at yet.
         */
        if(!Objects.equals(prevSampeId, result.getSample_id())){
            JSONObject row = new JSONObject();
            row.put("equipmentId", result.getEquipment_id());
            row.put("lot", result.getLot());
            row.put("wrkOrdId", result.getWrk_ord_i());
            row.put("opcodeDesc", result.getOpcode_desc());
            row.put("sampleId", result.getSample_id());
            row.put("sampleStatus", result.getSample_status());
            row.put("sCreatedDate", result.getS_created_date());
            row.put("sModifiedDate", result.getS_modified_date());
            row.put("sCollectionDate", result.getS_collection_date());
            row.put(result.getTm_id(), result.getResult());
            pivotData.add(row);
        }
        /*
         * Because results are already sorted by sample ID in ascending order,
         * if sample IDs match, we can get the last row in our pivot list, as it is the row we need to update
         * with new test method record.
         */
        else if (Objects.equals(prevSampeId, result.getSample_id())){
            JSONObject row = pivotData.get(pivotData.size() - 1);
            row.put(result.getTm_id(), result.getResult());
        }
        prevSampeId = result.getSample_id();
    }
    return pivotData;
}
```